# mySQL: show only 4 records per type, group by type

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have 2 columns Name and Type:

```
Name    | Type
==================
sam     | Blue  
john    | red  
jones   | Blue  
troy    | red  
dan     | red  
ben     | Blue  
joy     | Blue  
jim     | green  
tom     | red  
edi     | green  
frank   | green  
tony    | green  
jimmy   | red
```

How can I pull just 4 rows per Type, grouped by TYPE, Ordered by Type using mySQL?
My finish result should look like:

```
Name    | Type
==================
sam     | Blue   
jones   | Blue  
ben     | Blue  
joy     | Blue 
edi     | green  
frank   | green  
tony    | green  
jim     | green  
john    | red     
troy    | red  
dan     | red  
tom     | red
```

Comment: Use `.GroupBy()` function to group them on `Type` Use `.Take(4)` foreach group, to select top 4. Then `.OrderBy()` the `Type`

Comment: Ordered by type? Do you mean each row listed starting with the lowest first letter of the type? So for exampe, all the results that would be Blue first?

Comment: Or in SQL (my previous comment was Linq - much easier to enumerate in-code) - `GROUP BY`, then `SELECT TOP 4` (or `LIMIT`), then `ORDER BY`

Comment: Seems that way @GaryCarlyleCook, updated question has sample desired outcome

Comment: @GeoffJames , I never use Take(4) can you explain with an example?

Comment: They were just examples when you're using a Linq-compatible language to create enumerable objects to get your list (equivalent of shorthand Sql queries), sorry. My head was stuck in .NET mode _*facepalm*_

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I propose to do it:

A) Using MyISAM Engine and apply the auto_increment facility, but that involves using and extra table for staging storage:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE UserLikes(
Type varchar(20) ,
name varchar(20),
ranking int AUTO_INCREMENT,
likes int,
PRIMARY KEY ( type, ranking  )
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO UserLikes
SELECT 
Type,
Name,
null AS ranking,
count(*) AS likes
FROM 
YourTable
GROUP BY Type, Name 
ORDER BY Type, likes DESC;

SELECT * FROM UserLikes WHERE ranking <= 4;
```

B) The other way doesn't require any premissions except the Select accees 
grant but it would hang as the table grows so much:

```
SET @ranking = 0;
SET @currType = space(20);

SELECT 
    Types,
    Name,
    @ranking := IF( Type != @currType , 0 , @ranking + 1 ) AS ranking,
    @currType := Type,
    likes    
 FROM
(
   SELECT 
       Type,
       Name,
       null AS ranking,
       count(*) AS likes
   FROM 
       YourTable
   GROUP BY Type, Name,
   ORDER BY Type, likes DESC
) AS staging
HAVING ranking <= 4
;
```

I expect this could help to you.

Comment: how can this help me?

Comment: This kind of logics allow to you create a kind of Ranking by Categories such the one you describe in your post. You only have set correctly the field you want to group by and the order criteria, it gives you the possition (ranking) inside the category so you only have to query over this final table.

Comment: MyISAM auto_increment automatically assing to each element a possition and resets (or continue) the counting in each specific field change. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

To use group by you need to have a summary calculation function. For instance, if you want to count the number of types by color:

```
select count(name), type
from your_table
group by type
order by type
```

If what you want is just limit the number of rows you can get, you can use LIMIT clause.

```
select *
from your_table
limit 4;
```

Hope it helps :)

For edited version:

```
(select *
from your_table
where type="blue"
LIMIT 4)
UNION
(select *
from your_table
where type="green"
LIMIT 4)
UNION
(select *
from your_table
where type="red"
LIMIT 4)
```

I know it is not the most elegan solution, but I bet I'll work.

Solution 3:
This solution is rather complicated. You need to use MySql @vars, and a HAVING clause.

```
set @num := 0, @type := '';

select type, name,
      @num := if(@type = type, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @type := type as dummy
from your_table
group by type, name
having row_number <= 2;
```

Comment: But I need to pull 4 rows per each Type, group by Type

Comment: Please, have a look to solution 3

Comment: Did you change the table name "your_table" by the right name yours have?

Comment: the 3rd solution didn't work. I ended up uses the 2 Solution.